# 2 Pickers fetching from 2 Core Data Entities

Tags: swift, swiftui

Building my first app here, so I'm curious if I'm going about this the right way.

My app allows the user to create Accounts and Categories before creating an Expense object, which will allow the user to select an account and category to apply to the expense.

How can I fetch from both entities (Accounts and Categories) in a single view?

I tried including all Attributes under the Expenses entity, but it seems that when I save, it creates a new Expense in my ExpenseList view.

I have 3 CoreData entities, and two Pickers (for category and account)

**Expenses**

- expenseAccount:String
- expenseCategory:String
- expenseCost:Double
- expenseDate:Date
- expenseId:UUID
- expenseIsMonthly:Bool
- expenseName:String

**Categories**

- categoryName:String

**Accounts**

- accountName:String

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct ExpenseDetail: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Categories.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Categories.categoryName, ascending: true)
        ]
    )
    private var result: FetchedResults<Categories>
    
    var logToEdit: Expenses?
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var amount: String = ""
    @State var category: String = ""
    @State var date: Date = Date()
    @State var account: String = ""
    @State var isMonthly: Bool = false
    
    var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let f = NumberFormatter()
        f.numberStyle = .currency
        return f
    }()
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form{
                TextField("Expense Name", text: $name)
                Section{
                    HStack{
                        TextField("$\(amount)", text: $amount)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                            .disableAutocorrection(true).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date) {
                        Text("Date")
                    }.onAppear{self.hideKeyboard()}
                    
                    
                    Picker(selection: $category, label: Text("Category")) {
                        ForEach(result) { (log: Categories) in
                            Text(log.categoryName ?? "No Category").tag(log.categoryName)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Picker(selection: $account, label: Text("Account")) {
                        ForEach(result) { (log: Categories) in
                            self.Print("\(log.categoryName ?? "")")
                            Button(action: {
                                // TODO: Implement Edit
                            }) {
                                Text(log.categoryName!.capitalized).tag(self.category)
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    Toggle(isOn: $isMonthly) {
                        Text("Monthly Expense")
                    }.toggleStyle(CheckboxToggleStyle())
                }
                
                Section{
                    Button(action: {
                        onSaveTapped()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Save")
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                Section{
                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Cancel").foregroundColor(.red)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Add Expense")
        }
        
    }
    
    private func onSaveTapped() {
        
        let expenseLog: Expenses
        if let logToEdit = self.logToEdit {
            expenseLog = logToEdit
        } else {
            expenseLog = Expenses(context: self.context)
            expenseLog.expenseId = UUID()
        }
        
        expenseLog.expenseName = self.name
        expenseLog.expenseCategory = self.category
        print("\(expenseLog.expenseName ?? "") category Picker: \(self.category)")
        print("\(expenseLog.expenseName ?? "") ExpenseCategory: \(expenseLog.expenseCategory!)")
        expenseLog.expenseCost = Double(self.amount) ?? 0
        print("\(expenseLog.expenseName ?? "") Amount: \(self.amount)")
        print("\(expenseLog.expenseName ?? "")ExpenseCost: \(expenseLog.expenseCost)")
        expenseLog.expenseDate = self.date
        expenseLog.expenseAccount = self.account
        expenseLog.expenseIsMonthly = self.isMonthly
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
    
    
}
```

ExpenseList code, if needed:

```
        NavigationView{
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                List{
                    ForEach(result) { (log: Expenses) in
                        self.Print("\(log.expenseName ?? "") expenseCost: \(log.expenseCost)")
                        self.Print("\(log.expenseName ?? "") amountText: \(log.amountText)")
                        Button(action: {
                            // TODO: Implement Edit
                        }) {
                            HStack(spacing: 16) {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                                    Text(log.nameText).font(.headline)
                                    Text(log.dateText).font(.caption)
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 8){
                                    Text(log.amountText).font(.headline)
                                    Text(log.expenseAccount?.capitalized ?? "").font(.caption)
                                    Text(log.expenseCategory ?? "No Category")
                                }
                                
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical, 2)
                        }
                    }.onDelete(perform: onDelete)
                }.navigationTitle("Expense List")
                
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Button(action: {
                        // toggles the value of our bool from false to true,
                        // which will present our sheet.
                        self.addExpense.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                    })
                
                    .sheet(isPresented: $addExpense) {
                        ExpenseDetail()
                    }
                )
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
```

Code used to save Categories:

```
    private func onSaveTapped() {
    
        let log: Categories
        if let logToEdit = self.logToEdit {
            log = logToEdit
        } else {
            log = Categories(context: self.context)
        }
        
        log.categoryName = self.category

        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for way of fetching the saved entities?

Comment: Yes @AnjaliAggarwal. I want to fetch categoryName for one Picker and accountName for the other.

Comment: Are the two linked? If not the just add another fetch.  If the are then I would do a subview passing the requited information to get the correct data in the other picker.

Comment: Thanks @MwcsMac. They are not linked. Sorry to ask a very basic question but how would I add another fetch here? I tried adding a second Fetchrequest but I got 2 errors:
Generic parameter 'Result' could not be inferred
Value of type 'FetchedResults<_>' has no member 'wrappedValue'

Comment: @nastri83 The var can be what ever you want it to be.  Like `catresult` and `accountresult` or something that makes sense and identifies the results from the fetch.